# How do I wrap a div around specific fields in a view?

Tags: theming, 8

I have to make a small website using drupal 8 for a school project but I keep getting stuck with the twig templating. I'm trying to wrap a div around certain fields in drupal 8 with twig.
The layout at the moment is as follows(this is an example);

```
<div>
Content type image
</div>
<div>
Content type Title
Content type Category
</div>
```

Is there any way to accomplish this using a twig template for the certain view?

[image]

The bottom two items have to go in a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add CSS classes you don't need to use Twig, you can do it using the Views UI

Click on your field. Then under style settings, checkmark customize field HTMl and select DIV as your element. Checkmark create css class and type your class name.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In node.html.twig Twig you would do it like this:

```
<div class="cool">
  {{ content.title }}
</div>
<div class="kewl">
  {{ content.field_name }}
</div>
```

Comment: The excercise is using twig though, but It's interesting seeing that you can just use the views interface. Is there any way of calling just the image field for example in twig? Something like {{ content.field_image }} ?